# How can I get the content of a loaded file (with script or link)

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I was wondering, how I get the content of a loaded script, stylesheet, ... bye an accessing an id set on the element.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="../jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script id="test" src="test.txt" type="text/isis-template"></script>
    <!-- File contains "Hello world" -->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#test').GET_CONTENT_OF_LOADED_FILE
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Background: I want to load HTML templates (e.g. for mustach, knockout), but don't want to write them into the page, I'd rather have them in a seperate file. Now I saw that I can load any file with the script or link tag, so I was testing if I can load them like this....
Any comments why this might be a bad idea or how it can be done better are appreciated.

Comment: Based on what your wrote in background, I would consider doing this server side. You'll have less requests, and transmit less data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the content of **text/isis-template** file when document is ready?
You are lucky because this file doesn't fall for [CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) but mine(the answer i was looking for and came here today) do.

Well just do ajax!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Demo</title>
   <script src="../jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

   <!-- File contains "Hello world" -->
   <script>
     $(function () {
        $.ajax({ url: "test.html"})
         .done(function(cont) {
             var GET_CONTENT_OF_LOADED_FILE=cont;
         });
     });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: hey, well this is ~5 years old and wouldn't do it like this at all anymore... still I guess if you search for it, you should do it like this. Don't really remember what my problem back then was but now this all changes with angular, react, you name it

Answer (score 1):

Try using [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(function () {
      $('#test').load('yourfolder/test.html', function(resp){
           alert(resp); 
      });
});
```

If you have already load the contents in some html element

```
contents = $('#test').html();
```

Comment: I don't want to use load, or any Javascript command.... I want to use this file more like a code behind file for my local template resoruces, which isn't visible in the dom...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you use debug tools and see the network activity, you will see that it does not load the external files (*since it is not a `text/javascript`, and the browser does not know how to handle it*)</strike>
(*wrong test on my part, was testing local files*)

So you only have a tag there with an `id` and an external resource in the `src` attribute. Treat it as just metadata.

You will have to manually load the resources

something like this

```
// load external template resources
$('script[type="text/isis-template"]').each(function(){
    $(this).load(this.src);
});
```

*For actual use you would need to make sure the templates are loaded before you try using them..*

Comment: I just checked in all major browsers (CC, FF, IE7+) and debuggin tool always show me netowrk activity, laoding the file....

Comment: Is it true for any browser that it doesn't load external files?

Comment: indeed... i was checking with local files, not on a server. But still the browser expects code to be executed in the global scope. Since it is not of that type you can not access it as text..

Comment: could I load html (type="text/html")

Comment: @stefan, in my knowledge only actual script code will work.. anything else will not be accessible as text..